# How to use horizontal and vertical scroll side by side using scrollmagic and Gsap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, gsap, scrollmagic

I am trying to use vertical and horizontal scroll in the same div using scrollmagic and gsap but some vertical scroll is not equal to the horizontal scroll displacement. I am a screen and codepen link for reference.

I have tried to manual set the vertical div to horizontal div displacement but it's not working on different screen sizes.
`enter code here`
https://codepen.io/Dushyant9211/pen/Lwpebj
Please go through this link of code refernce

Comment: What's your end goal? How does the demo "not work" on different screen sizes? See [this article on GreenSock's site](https://greensock.com/scrollmagic) for more demos of how to use GSAP with ScrollMagic.

Comment: My End goal is that both div end in equal time. Right now it's only working for Macbook air only but if you check on some other screen like mac pro or imac 27" its not working fine.

Comment: Sorry, I still am not understanding what you're trying to do exactly. The demo is different than it was yesterday. Are you talking about lining up the images moving horizontally with the sections that go vertically? On what screen sizes do you have an issue?

Comment: Zach, right now I have left div where I have 3 description content and right div I have 3 images. Every image is related to the content. So when I scroll the div I want both image and content comes at the same time. Right now they are coming at different time for 2nd and 3rd section.